# How can I improve these multiple if statements?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
    if (gepakteLucifers == 1) {
        printf("De computer pakt 3 lucifers\n");
        printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 3, lucifers - 3);
        lucifers = lucifers - 3;
    }
    if (gepakteLucifers == 2) {
        printf("De computer pakt 2 lucifers\n");
        printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 2, lucifers - 2); 
        lucifers = lucifers - 2;
    }
    if (gepakteLucifers == 3) {
        printf("De computer pakt 1 lucifer\n");
        printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 1, lucifers - 1); 
        lucifers = lucifers - 1;
    }
```

There are too many `if` statements. It needs to be simplified but I don't know how.
**edit** : this is for `nim` game so when the player picks 3 the computer has to pick 1, if the player picks 2 the computer has to pick 2, if the player picks 3 the computer has to pick 1. And that's it.

Comment: Looks like very basic logic to be. Kind of like: 1 -> 3, 2-> 2, 3 -> 1. Hint: `4-gepakteLucifers`...

Comment: You can also use `switch` and `case` since you operate on ints

Comment: With the three values used for `gepakteLucifers` in your question, what is the result of `4 - gepakteLucifers`? Perhaps that result could be used?

Comment: `lucifers -= (4 - gepakteLucifers);`

Comment: You don't need any `if()` statements at all. `int adjustment=4-gepakteLucifer; printf("De computer pakt %d lucifers\n", adjustment); printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, adjustment, lucifers-adjustment); lucifers -= adjustment;`

Comment: What shall happen if `gepakteLucifers` is less than 1 or bigger than 3?

Comment: @thebusybee then it returns 0 it has to be 1, 2 or 3. its the nim game.

Comment: Instead of multiple if statements you can add else if. Program will be more efficient and program will enter only one branch.

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your code excerpt (this is why it is recommended to provide a [mre]). Does it mean that if such an out-of-bounds value is used, _nothing_ shall happen?

Comment: @r3mainer this works, except if i let the player pick 5 or higher, or -1 or lower...  then the system says "you can only pick 1, 2 or 3." that is right, but then it also lets the computer pick -1 for example. the computer schould also be able to only pick 1, 2, or 3. (its the nim game) (im a complete beginner btw sorry)

Comment: Then please show us *how* the computer picks its numbers.

Comment: @quiana all the ifs are needed? because as per your explanation in your question, else if should work. and if yes it will be easier to merge these if conditions

Comment: "There are too many if statements. It needs to be simplified but I don't know how." hmm... why? what problem are you addressing? performance? maintenance? readability? There are several ways to get rid of the if-statements but (most likely) they will all make the code harder to read.... so is it worth it? BTW: `else if` for the last two if-statements would probably not hurt ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you are focussing on the right problem? The challenge of nim is not what the opponent took away, but how many remain (and this extends up to 4 for the bottom row.) The code above doesn't seem appropriate to the game strategy...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` statement:

```c
switch(gepakteLucifers){
case 1:
    printf("De computer pakt 3 lucifers\n");
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 3, lucifers - 3);
    lucifers = lucifers - 3;
    break;

case 2:
    printf("De computer pakt 2 lucifers\n");
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 2, lucifers - 2); 
    lucifers = lucifers - 2;
    break;

case 3:
    printf("De computer pakt 1 lucifer\n");
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 1, lucifers - 1); 
    lucifers = lucifers - 1;
    break;
default:
}
```

---

However, since the only different operation you're doing inside the *if conditions* is `lucifers = lucifers - something`, you could just write a single `lucifers -= 4 - gepakteLucifers;`:

```c
printf("De computer pakt %d lucifers\n", 4 - gepakteLucifers);
printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 4 - gepakteLucifers, lucifers - (4 - gepakteLucifers));
lucifers -= 4 - gepakteLucifers;
```

Moreover, you said the user cannot enter a number lower than 1 or greater than 3, therefore you should check if the input is correct and, if it's not, ask to enter it again. For example using a `while()`:

```c
printf("Input: ");
while ((scanf("%d", &gepakteLucifers) != 1) || (gepakteLucifers < 1 || gepakteLucifers > 3)) {
    printf("Input must be 1, 2 or 3\nInput: ");
}
```

Comment: @mikyll98 thanks, but when the player picks 3 the computer needs to pick 1, so does it still work that way?

Comment: @quiana _"but when the player picks 3 the computer needs to pick 1"_: what is 4 - 3 ?

Comment: @quiana obviously it does, `lucifers -= 4 - gepakteLucifers;` means: "from `lucifers` subtract `4 - gepakteLucifers`", therefore if `gepakteLucifers` is 3, `lucifers` will become `4 - 3` (which is 1)

Comment: @quiana You should learn [how to use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to watch your program stepping through the statements and see the values in the variables.

Comment: Consider introducing a [variable](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd6a7oGb5) `int const value = 4 - gepakteLucifers;`, instead of repeat code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky im sorry i know 4-3 is 1... i meant like when i (the player) picks for example 5 the system prints "you can only pick 1, 2, or 3" what it should do so this is correct, but then the computer picks -1. that it shouldnt do. the computer should also only be able to pick 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: @quiana then make a test like `if (gepakteLucifers < 1 || gepakteLucifers > 3) ...` meaning if number of matches enteres is smaller than 1 or larger than 3 then do something...

Comment: @Jabberwocky or make it a loop condition and ask again to enter a valid input

Answer (score 0):

as per the explanation of yours in the question body,

multiple if conditions can be merged into a single if condition,

what you can do is,

you can make one function which takes the argument as n

like

```
void func(unsigned int n){
        if ((n > 0 && n < 4) && (gepakteLucifers == n)){
            printf("De computer pakt %d lucifers\n",4-n);
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n\n", lucifers, 4-n, 4-lucifers - n);
            lucifers = lucifers - (4-n);
        }
        return;
}
```

here you can pass the no. n as 1 2 or 3 or any positive int

it will check the condition and compare the value with the `gepakteLucifers` and also check for the value range of the entered argument

you also can discard the function and take only the new variable if it is more convenient

hope this may help you to improve the code!!